# Is there a way to configure custom keyboard layouts?

Tags: keyboard

There are a lot of apps out on the market that you can install to have a customized Keyboard with different languages and functionality, but I didn't find a way to get my own custom Keyboard layout on my device.

Is it possible to get this running easily?

I would like to have the left half of [the single handed Coffee++ Layout](http://coffeeplusplus.z11.de/) on my device:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this (although I can't say it will be too easy) is to create your own custom [IME](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html) (input method editor).

While it may seem like a daunting task, and there is a good chance that it is, you aren't the only one who wants their own input method. So here is a pretty popular Stack OverFlow that could help you out: [How to develop a soft keyboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3480715/how-to-develop-a-soft-keyboard-for-android)